# Android VNC project that I downloaded has a lot of errors

Tags: android, eclipse, vnc-viewer

I downloaded the android-vnc-viewer project from [this link](https://code.google.com/archive/p/android-vnc-viewer/source/default/source)

I imported the "eclipse projects" in the trunk folder. This is giving a lot of error. Since it's a complete project, it shouldn't have any code errors(which I'm getting). It's not a gradle project. Please help me out. What have I missed?

Edit:
Errors:

```
    Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The method toString() of type ConnectionBean must override or implement a supertype method  ConnectionBean.java /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 67 Java Problem
The method setUserName(String) is undefined for the type ConnectionBean ConnectionBean.java /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 29 Java Problem
The method setUserName(String) is undefined for the type ConnectionBean androidVNC.java /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 260    Java Problem
The method setUseRepeater(boolean) is undefined for the type ConnectionBean androidVNC.java /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 269    Java Problem
The method setUseRepeater(boolean) is undefined for the type ConnectionBean androidVNC.java /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 273    Java Problem
The method setUseLocalCursor(boolean) is undefined for the type ConnectionBean  androidVNC.java /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 264    Java Problem
The method setScaleModeAsString(String) is undefined for the type ConnectionBean    ConnectionBean.java /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 63 Java Problem
The method setRepeaterId(String) is undefined for the type ConnectionBean   ConnectionBean.java /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 34 Java Problem
The method setRepeaterId(String) is undefined for the type ConnectionBean   androidVNC.java /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 268    Java Problem
The method setPort(int) is undefined for the type ConnectionBean    ConnectionBean.java /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 30 Java Problem
The method setPort(int) is undefined for the type ConnectionBean    VncCanvasActivity.java  /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 574    Java Problem
The method setPort(int) is undefined for the type ConnectionBean    VncCanvasActivity.java  /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 593    Java Problem
The method setPort(int) is undefined for the type ConnectionBean    VncCanvasActivity.java  /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 600    Java Problem
The method setPort(int) is undefined for the type ConnectionBean    androidVNC.java /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 253    Java Problem
The method setPassword(String) is undefined for the type ConnectionBean ConnectionBean.java /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 26 Java Problem
The method setPassword(String) is undefined for the type ConnectionBean VncCanvasActivity.java  /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 580    Java Problem
The method setPassword(String) is undefined for the type ConnectionBean androidVNC.java /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 262    Java Problem
The method setNickname(String) is undefined for the type ConnectionBean ConnectionBean.java /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 28 Java Problem
The method setNickname(String) is undefined for the type ConnectionBean androidVNC.java /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 259    Java Problem
The method setMouseClick(boolean) is undefined for the type MetaKeyBean MetaKeyBean.java    /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 208    Java Problem
The method setMouseClick(boolean) is undefined for the type MetaKeyBean MetaKeyBean.java    /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 233    Java Problem
The method setMouseButtons(int) of type MetaKeyBean must override or implement a supertype method   MetaKeyBean.java    /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 230    Java Problem
The method setMetaListId(long) is undefined for the type MetaKeyBean    MetaKeyBean.java    /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 142    Java Problem
The method setMetaListId(int) is undefined for the type ConnectionBean  ConnectionBean.java /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 35 Java Problem
The method setMetaListId(int) is undefined for the type ConnectionBean  MetaKeyDialog.java  /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 108    Java Problem
The method setMetaFlags(int) of type MetaKeyBean must override or implement a supertype method  MetaKeyBean.java    /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 218    Java Problem
The method setLastMetaKeyId(int) is undefined for the type ConnectionBean   MetaKeyDialog.java  /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 150    Java Problem
The method setKeySym(int) of type MetaKeyBean must override or implement a supertype method MetaKeyBean.java    /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 205    Java Problem
The method setKeyDesc(String) of type MetaKeyBean must override or implement a supertype method MetaKeyBean.java    /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 196    Java Problem
The method setKeepPassword(boolean) is undefined for the type ConnectionBean    ConnectionBean.java /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 27 Java Problem
The method setKeepPassword(boolean) is undefined for the type ConnectionBean    androidVNC.java /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 263    Java Problem
The method setInputMode(String) is undefined for the type ConnectionBean    AbstractScaling.java    /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 95 Java Problem
The method setInputMode(String) is undefined for the type ConnectionBean    ConnectionBean.java /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 33 Java Problem
The method setInputMode(String) is undefined for the type ConnectionBean    VncCanvasActivity.java  /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 905    Java Problem
The method setInputMode(String) is undefined for the type ConnectionBean    VncCanvasActivity.java  /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 1198   Java Problem
The method setInputMode(String) is undefined for the type ConnectionBean    VncCanvasActivity.java  /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 1444   Java Problem
The method setForceFull(long) is undefined for the type ConnectionBean  androidVNC.java /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 261    Java Problem
The method setFollowPan(boolean) is undefined for the type ConnectionBean   VncCanvasActivity.java  /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 880    Java Problem
The method setFollowMouse(boolean) is undefined for the type ConnectionBean VncCanvasActivity.java  /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 871    Java Problem
The method setFollowMouse(boolean) is undefined for the type ConnectionBean VncCanvasActivity.java  /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 907    Java Problem
The method setColorModel(String) is undefined for the type ConnectionBean   ConnectionBean.java /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 31 Java Problem
The method setColorModel(String) is undefined for the type ConnectionBean   VncCanvasActivity.java  /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 577    Java Problem
The method setColorModel(String) is undefined for the type ConnectionBean   VncCanvasActivity.java  /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 1022   Java Problem
The method setColorModel(String) is undefined for the type ConnectionBean   androidVNC.java /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 265    Java Problem
The method setAddress(String) is undefined for the type ConnectionBean  ConnectionBean.java /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 25 Java Problem
The method setAddress(String) is undefined for the type ConnectionBean  VncCanvasActivity.java  /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 572    Java Problem
The method setAddress(String) is undefined for the type ConnectionBean  VncCanvasActivity.java  /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 603    Java Problem
The method setAddress(String) is undefined for the type ConnectionBean  androidVNC.java /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 250    Java Problem
The method set_Id(int) is undefined for the type ConnectionBean ConnectionBean.java /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 24 Java Problem
The method set_Id(int) is undefined for the type ConnectionBean androidVNC.java /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 180    Java Problem
The method isMouseClick() is undefined for the type MetaKeyBean MetaKeyBean.java    /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 132    Java Problem
The method isMouseClick() is undefined for the type MetaKeyBean MetaKeyBean.java    /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 180    Java Problem
The method isMouseClick() is undefined for the type MetaKeyBean MetaKeyBean.java    /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 206    Java Problem
The method isMouseClick() is undefined for the type MetaKeyBean MetaKeyBean.java    /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 231    Java Problem
The method isMouseClick() is undefined for the type MetaKeyBean MetaKeyDialog.java  /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 553    Java Problem
The method isMouseClick() is undefined for the type MetaKeyBean VncCanvas.java  /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 946    Java Problem
The method getUserName() is undefined for the type ConnectionBean   VncCanvas.java  /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 165    Java Problem
The method getUserName() is undefined for the type ConnectionBean   VncCanvas.java  /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 229    Java Problem
The method getUserName() is undefined for the type ConnectionBean   androidVNC.java /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 214    Java Problem
The method getUseRepeater() is undefined for the type ConnectionBean    VncCanvas.java  /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 212    Java Problem
The method getUseRepeater() is undefined for the type ConnectionBean    androidVNC.java /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 224    Java Problem
The method getUseLocalCursor() is undefined for the type ConnectionBean AbstractBitmapData.java /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 49 Java Problem
The method getUseLocalCursor() is undefined for the type ConnectionBean AbstractBitmapDrawable.java /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 44 Java Problem
The method getUseLocalCursor() is undefined for the type ConnectionBean FullBufferBitmapData.java   /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 77 Java Problem
The method getUseLocalCursor() is undefined for the type ConnectionBean androidVNC.java /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 212    Java Problem
The method getScaleModeAsString() is undefined for the type ConnectionBean  ConnectionBean.java /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 58 Java Problem
The method getRepeaterId() is undefined for the type ConnectionBean VncCanvas.java  /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 212    Java Problem
The method getRepeaterId() is undefined for the type ConnectionBean VncCanvas.java  /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 212    Java Problem
The method getRepeaterId() is undefined for the type ConnectionBean VncCanvas.java  /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 217    Java Problem
The method getRepeaterId() is undefined for the type ConnectionBean VncCanvas.java  /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 217    Java Problem
The method getRepeaterId() is undefined for the type ConnectionBean androidVNC.java /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 224    Java Problem
The method getPort() is undefined for the type ConnectionBean   ConnectionBean.java /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 72 Java Problem
The method getPort() is undefined for the type ConnectionBean   ConnectionBean.java /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 84 Java Problem
The method getPort() is undefined for the type ConnectionBean   ConnectionBean.java /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 84 Java Problem
The method getPort() is undefined for the type ConnectionBean   VncCanvas.java  /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 206    Java Problem
The method getPort() is undefined for the type ConnectionBean   VncCanvas.java  /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 208    Java Problem
The method getPort() is undefined for the type ConnectionBean   VncCanvasActivity.java  /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 592    Java Problem
The method getPort() is undefined for the type ConnectionBean   androidVNC.java /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 206    Java Problem
The method getPassword() is undefined for the type ConnectionBean   VncCanvas.java  /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 165    Java Problem
The method getPassword() is undefined for the type ConnectionBean   androidVNC.java /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 207    Java Problem
The method getPassword() is undefined for the type ConnectionBean   androidVNC.java /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 208    Java Problem
The method getNickname() is undefined for the type ConnectionBean   ConnectionBean.java /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 72 Java Problem
The method getNickname() is undefined for the type ConnectionBean   ConnectionBean.java /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 80 Java Problem
The method getNickname() is undefined for the type ConnectionBean   ConnectionBean.java /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 80 Java Problem
The method getNickname() is undefined for the type ConnectionBean   ConnectionListActivity.java /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 102    Java Problem
The method getNickname() is undefined for the type ConnectionBean   androidVNC.java /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 177    Java Problem
The method getNickname() is undefined for the type ConnectionBean   androidVNC.java /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 178    Java Problem
The method getNickname() is undefined for the type ConnectionBean   androidVNC.java /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 185    Java Problem
The method getNickname() is undefined for the type ConnectionBean   androidVNC.java /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 213    Java Problem
The method getMouseButtons() is undefined for the type MetaKeyBean  MetaKeyBean.java    /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 133    Java Problem
The method getMouseButtons() is undefined for the type MetaKeyBean  MetaKeyBean.java    /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 181    Java Problem
The method getMouseButtons() is undefined for the type MetaKeyBean  MetaKeyBean.java    /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 231    Java Problem
The method getMouseButtons() is undefined for the type MetaKeyBean  MetaKeyDialog.java  /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 555    Java Problem
The method getMouseButtons() is undefined for the type MetaKeyBean  VncCanvas.java  /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 949    Java Problem
The method getMostRecent(SQLiteDatabase) from the type androidVNC refers to the missing type MostRecentBean IntroTextDialog.java    /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 43 Java Problem
The method getMostRecent(SQLiteDatabase) from the type androidVNC refers to the missing type MostRecentBean IntroTextDialog.java    /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 145    Java Problem
The method getMostRecent(SQLiteDatabase) from the type androidVNC refers to the missing type MostRecentBean VncCanvasActivity.java  /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 562    Java Problem
The method getMostRecent(SQLiteDatabase) from the type androidVNC refers to the missing type MostRecentBean androidVNC.java /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 306    Java Problem
The method getMostRecent(SQLiteDatabase) from the type androidVNC refers to the missing type MostRecentBean androidVNC.java /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 363    Java Problem
The method getMetaListId() is undefined for the type MetaKeyBean    MetaKeyBean.java    /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 136    Java Problem
AbstractConnectionBean cannot be resolved to a variable VncDatabase.java    /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 88 Java Problem
AbstractConnectionBean cannot be resolved to a variable VncDatabase.java    /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 88 Java Problem
AbstractConnectionBean cannot be resolved to a variable VncDatabase.java    /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 87 Java Problem
AbstractConnectionBean cannot be resolved to a variable VncDatabase.java    /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 87 Java Problem
AbstractConnectionBean cannot be resolved to a variable VncDatabase.java    /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 78 Java Problem
AbstractConnectionBean cannot be resolved to a variable VncDatabase.java    /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 78 Java Problem
AbstractConnectionBean cannot be resolved to a variable VncDatabase.java    /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 77 Java Problem
AbstractConnectionBean cannot be resolved to a variable VncDatabase.java    /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 77 Java Problem
AbstractConnectionBean cannot be resolved to a variable VncDatabase.java    /androidVNC/src/android/androidVNC  line 71 Java Problem
```

Comment: Without telling us any of the errors you receive, we will have a hard time guessing what's going wrong.

Comment: I could add around 70% of the errors. The characters size was larger than the limit.